# Get to the last node of linked list without traversing whole list

Tags: linked-list, nodes, traversal

I was asked this question in an interview:

> You are given the pointer to the header but you are not allowed to
>   traverse the whole list. How will you get to the last node?

I tried myself but failed to come up to any answer. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you sure it is complete question? You just have a root and reference to next element. How can you get to the last element without going through all elements?

Comment: Thats what I said to the interviewer

Answer (score 3):

The term "head*er*" implies more than just a pointer to the head node. Given that the typical linked-list header contains the pointers `*head`, `*current` and `*tail`, I would suggest that this question is a test of idiomatic rather than algorithmic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

See, I don't find a way to traverse to the last node in a linked list just in a swish. 
Perhaps there is a way of doing that but that's not direct. You may have a circular linked list at your disposal. That circulat list must be a **two way circular linked list**
Here is the code for  a two way circular linked list implementation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

//Structure for Two Way Circular Linked List

struct node
{
            int data;
            struct node *prev;
            struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;

//Prototype Declaration
void createList(int);
void display(void);
void addbeg(int);
void addspec(int,int);
void search(int);
void evenodd(void);

//Main Function Start From Here
void main()
{
            int ch,num,pos;
            clrscr();
            do
            {
                        printf("\n1.Create Linked List");
                        printf("\n2.Display Linked List");
                        printf("\n3.Add At Beginning");
                        printf("\n4.Add At Specific Location");
                        printf("\n5.Search Element in List");
                        printf("\n6.Even Odd Calculations");
                        printf("\n7.Exit");
                        printf("\nEnter Your Choice");
                        scanf("%d",&ch);
                        switch(ch)
                        {
                                    case 1:
                                                printf("Enter any Number");
                                                scanf("%d",&num);
                                                createList(num);
                                                break;
                                    case 2:
                                                display();
                                                break;
                                    case 3:
                                                printf("Enter any Number to add at Beginning");
                                                scanf("%d",&num);
                                                addbeg(num);
                                                break;
                                    case 4:
                                                printf("Enter any Number and its Position");
                                                scanf("%d%d",&num,&pos);
                                                addspec(num,pos);
                                                break;
                                    case 5:
                                                printf("Enter any Number to Search");
                                                scanf("%d",&num);
                                                search(num);
                                                break;
                                    case 6:
                                                evenodd();
                                                break;
                                    case 7:
                                                exit(0);
                                    default:
                                                printf("Invalid Choice");
                        }
            }while(1);
}
//Create Two Way Circular Linked List
void createList(int num)
{
            struct node *q,*temp;
            if(start==NULL)
            {
                        start=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        start->data=num;
                        start->prev=start;
                        start->next=start;
            }
            else
            {
                        q=start;

                        //Traverse List Till End
                        while(q->next!=start)
                                    q=q->next;

                        //Add New Node At the End
                        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        temp->data=num;
                        temp->next=start;
                        start->prev=temp;
                        q->next=temp;
                        q->next->prev=q;
            }
}

//Display Elements of List
void display(void)
{
            struct node *q=start;
            do
            {
                        printf("%d\t",q->data);
                        q=q->next;
            }while(q!=start);
}

//Add At Beginning in Two Way Circular Linked List
void addbeg(int num)
{
            struct node *q=start,*temp;

            //Traverse List Till End
            while(q->next!=start)
                        q=q->next;

            //Add New Node At Beginning
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            temp->next=start;
            q->next=temp;
            start->prev=temp;
            temp->prev=q;
            start=temp;
}

//Add At Specific Position in Two Way Circular Linked List
void addspec(int num,int pos)
{
            struct node *q=start,*temp;
            int i;
            for(i=1;i<pos-1;i++)
                        q=q->next;

            //Add New Node At Specific Position
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            temp->next=q->next;
            q->next->prev=temp;
            q->next=temp;
            q->next->prev=q;
}

//Search Element into List
void search(int num)
{
            struct node *q=start;
            int count,i=0,flag=0;
            do
            {
                        if(q->data==num)
                        {
                                    flag=1;
                                    count=i;
                                    break;
                        }
                        i++;
                        q=q->next;
            }while(q!=start);
            if(flag==1)
                        printf("Element Found At Location %d",count+1);
            else
                        printf("No Element Found");
}

//Even Odd Calculation
void evenodd(void)
{
            struct node *q=start;
            int esum=0,osum=0,tsum=0,ec=0,oc=0,tc=0;
            do
            {
                        if(q->data%2==0)
                        {
                                    esum+=q->data;
                                    ec++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                    osum+=q->data;
                                    oc++;
                        }
                        tsum+=q->data;
                        tc++;
                        q=q->next;
            }while(q!=start);
            printf("\nEven Sum=%d",esum);
            printf("\nOdd Sum=%d",osum);
            printf("\nTotal Sum=%d",tsum);
            printf("\nEven Count=%d",ec);
            printf("\nOdd Count=%d",oc);
            printf("\nTotal Count=%d",tc);
}
```

Now, I gave you the concept or the way this could be done (**moving from head to last node**). Hope this answer suffice you and What I personally feel that the interviewer might have been testing your concepts. 
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can also track a pointer say 'lastNode' which gets updated at every insert operation in the list.

Comment: Post as a comment.